# Securing Web Flow in Grails using Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-webflow

According to [Spring Web Flow docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch07.html) it is possible to secure flow states using [SecurityFlowExecutionListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch07s04.html)

How can I do it in Grails ?

I am trying to achieve demanding authentification in the middle of the flow.